# Ubuntu 16.04 battery percentage 0% when time OK

Tags: 16.04, power-management, battery

First I'd like to inform that I ran over many of similar topics not only here on askubuntu but I can't find any suggestions that would help in my case.

I have a problem after doing upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS. The battery indicator on the right corner of the screen shows proper "time left" value but always 0%.

acpitool seems to show proper values:

```
$ acpitool -B
Battery #1     : present
Remaining capacity : 20520 mWh, 100.0%, 01:07:17
Design capacity    : 86580 mWh, 0.000% of design capacity
Capacity loss      : 100.0%
Present rate       : 18295 mW
Charging state     : Discharging
Battery type       : Unknown 
Model number       : DELL
Serial number      : 0001
```

but acpi info seems to be quite wrong:

```
$ acpi -V
Battery 0: Discharging, 0%, 00:53:39 remaining
Battery 0: design capacity 8142 mAh, last full capacity 0 mAh = 0%
Adapter 0: off-line
Cooling 0: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 1: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 3: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 4: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 10
```

The battery isn't the original one, It is a Green Cell Pro extended battery, but it was working just fine untill I made an upgrade to Ubuntu 16.

[here is a screen from my gnome-power-statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HygD5.png)

UPDATE:
It seems that capacity information is not properly stored  in

```
# AC plugged in
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT1
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Charging
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Unknown
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=11100000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=11708000
POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=30604000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=86580000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=0
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=22840000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=0
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=DELL YJNKK18C
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=Dynapack
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=0001

# AC pluggen out
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT1
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Unknown
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=11100000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=11706000
POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=17336000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=86580000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=0
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=22910000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=0
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=DELL YJNKK18C
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=Dynapack
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=0001
```

UPDATE 2:

Temporary fix to prevent system goes hibernate just after start (If you have UPower it controls low energy policy via percentage usage by default - which is broken). So we tell UPower to use time left policy:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/UPower/UPower.conf
```

change

```
UsePercentageForPolicy=true
```

to

```
UsePercentageForPolicy=false
```

save and restart upower service:

```
$ sudo service upower restart
```